# Azure Devops React Build using Wrong Environment File

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a very specific problem with Azure Devops building a React Application.

In my directory, I have two .env files that are used in the build of a React App for two different environments.  Essentially the .env files look something like this:

Environment1:

```
REACT_APP_API_URL: "env1's api url"
REACT_APP_FEATURE_1: true
```

Environment2:

```
REACT_APP_API_URL: "env2's api url"
REACT_APP_FEATURE_2: false
```

I use this command in the yaml in DevOps to build the React App per the selected environment:

```
- script: node -r dotenv/config node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js --max_old_space_size=4096 build dotenv_config_path=.env.$(ENVIRONMENT)
          displayName: "Building react for ${{ parameters.environment }} environment"
          timeoutInMinutes: 10
```

When building, this is all correct, it selects Environment1 in this particular instance.
However, once the build is done, in the React app for Environment1, it seems to build with the following configuration:

```
REACT_APP_API_URL: "env1's api url"
REACT_APP_FEATURE_1: true
REACT_APP_FEATURE_2: false
```

It seems to be building with the correct .env file for most of the configuration in it, but somehow gets configuration from an entirely different .env file added to it.

I am not sure why this would be happening in Azure DevOps, any help in the right direction will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue should comes from your YAML definition.

Try this:

```
trigger:
- none
parameters:
- name: environment 
  type: object
  default:
  - name: Environemt1
    value: .env.dev
  - name: Environemt2
    value: .env.prod

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
  - stage:
    jobs:                                        #foreach and put your logic below.
    - ${{ each env in parameters.environment }}:
      - job:
        pool:
          vmImage: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
        - task: PowerShell@2
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              Write-Host ${{ env.value }}
```

Results:

[image]

[image]